# How to reorder columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to programming. I am learning python and pandas from the internet.

I am working as a QA and trying to automate one of my manual work.

I have 2 datasets.

```py
df1= pd.DataFrame({'number':['c-101','c-102','c-103'],'Summary':['Summary1','Summary2','Summary3']})

df2= pd.DataFrame({'ticket':['c-102','c-103','c-101'],'Summary':['Ticket1','Ticket2','Ticket3'], 'Priority':['High','Low','High']})
```

`df2.ticket` contains similar values as `df1.numbers` but it is shuffled.

`df2` and `df1` have different lengths with `len(df1)` > `len(df2)`

I am trying to create a new dataframe (df3) where :

- if `df1.number` = `df2.ticket exist` : Update df3 with all the values in df1 (row) the corresponding df2.Priority (in a new column)
- if `df1.number = df2.ticket` don't exist : Update `"NO PRIORITY"`

So I need to loop through `df1.number` to check if each `df2.ticket` exist.

I tried:

```
for i in df2["ticket"]:
    if i in df1["number"]:
        ticket.append(df2["Priority"])
    else:
        ticket.append("NOT CREATED")
```

Output: df3 has all rows with Priority = "NOT CREATED" (even for `df1.number` = `df2.ticket`)

Really appreciate any input from community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `merge`, `join` or `pd.concat` for this:

**Input data:**

```
>>> print(df1)
  number   Summary
0  c-101  Summary1
1  c-102  Summary2
2  c-103  Summary3
3  c-104  Summary4

>>> print(df2)
  ticket  Summary Priority
0  c-102  Ticket1     High
1  c-103  Ticket2      Low
2  c-101  Ticket3     High
```

**Dataframe `merge`**:

```
>>> df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_on='number', right_on='ticket')
>>> df3['Priority'].fillna("NOT CREATED",inplace=True)
```

**Dataframe `join`**:

```
>>> df3 = df1.join(df2, how='outer', lsuffix='number',rsuffix='ticket')
>>> df3['Priority'] = df3['Priority'].fillna("NOT CREATED")
```

**Output in either case:**

```
>>> print(df3)
  number Summary_x ticket Summary_y     Priority
0  c-101  Summary1  c-101   Ticket3         High
1  c-102  Summary2  c-102   Ticket1         High
2  c-103  Summary3  c-103   Ticket2          Low
3  c-104  Summary4    NaN       NaN  NOT CREATED
```

**`pd.concat`**:

```
>>> df3 = pd.concat([df1.set_index('number'),df2.set_index('ticket')],axis=1)
>>> df3['Priority'] = df3['Priority'].fillna("NOT CREATED")
```

```
>>> df3
        Summary  Summary     Priority
c-101  Summary1  Ticket3         High
c-102  Summary2  Ticket1         High
c-103  Summary3  Ticket2          Low
c-104  Summary4      NaN  NOT CREATED
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your problem, this should do the job :

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='number', 'right_on'='ticket')
df3['Priority'].fillna('NO PRIORITY', inplace=True)
```